# using userAgent String How to find request comes from only mobile devices?

Tags: iphone, windows, spring, user-agent, mobile-browser

In case of Android phone I checked a condition using.
if (userAgent.contains("Mobile"))
but how to check for windows phone or i-phone? not for tablet.
In case of windown phone Will i check many conditions for browser like uc-browser or opera mini.
please confirm me Does userAgent contain common string? using this we recognize request comes from mobile?

Comment: Have you tried [Spring Mobile](http://projects.spring.io/spring-mobile/)?

Comment: NO I am not using spring-mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to detect Mobile in iOS devices :

```
 if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone)/))
       return true;
```

And you can detect mobile device for android OS as described by Google in the following link:

https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/mo-better-to-also-detect-mobile-user.html

And for Windows Phone use the following condition:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i) || 
   navigator.userAgent.match(/iemobile/i) || 
   navigator.userAgent.match(/WPDesktop/i)){

    return true;
}
```

Comment: for windows platform ?